# Autosize UITableViewCell with two columns

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a UITableViewCell that has two columns in it. Each column is a UILabel and each label is multiline (numberOfLines = 0).

What I would like is to have the table view cell vertically sized based on whichever label is taller. I have constraints setup for the left right and top of each label, but I am not sure how to add the bottom constraints since it needs to be a constraint on the tallest label.

Here is what I have right now:

[image]

But this is what I am trying to achieve. But either the left or the right column could be taller. In the picture, the right column is taller, but it just as well could be the left column depending on the data supplied to it.
[image]

I have thought about adding a height constraint to constraint both labels to the same height and then adding the bottom constraint from there, but then the shorter label will not be vertically aligned, or I do not know of a way of aligning them vertically without subclassing UILabel or using UITextView, which I would prefer to not do if possible.

Is there a good way to have the table view cell be able to vertically auto-size based on whichever column is taller? Thanks for your help.

---

## Update

I have added two additional constraints based on the answer provided. But for some reason I still cannot get it to autosize the table cell. I have the row height set to automatic in Interface Builder. Here are the constraints I have configured currently.

[image]

Is there anything in the constraints that would prevent the table view cell from increasing in height to match the height of the labels?

I am not sure if this is the problem or not, but I tried to add a low priority height constraint to the content view also, as was suggested, but I am unable to add the constraint or I do not know how to do that. I can add a height constraint to other views, but not to the content view of the table view cell.

## Update 2

Here are the constraints in code. This is in a UITableViewCell subclass and this code runs as part of the initialization of the cell.

```
[self addSubview:self.firstLabel];
[self addSubview:self.secondLabel];

NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [self.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:1.0f];
[heightConstraint setPriority:50];

[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
    [self.firstLabel.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor],
    [self.firstLabel.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor constant:0.0f],
    [self.firstLabel.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.centerXAnchor constant:-4.0f],
    
    [self.secondLabel.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.centerXAnchor constant:4.0f],
    [self.secondLabel.firstBaselineAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.firstLabel.firstBaselineAnchor],
    [self.secondLabel.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor],
    
    [self.contentView.heightAnchor constraintGreaterThanOrEqualToAnchor:self.firstLabel.heightAnchor constant:8.0f],
    [self.contentView.heightAnchor constraintGreaterThanOrEqualToAnchor:self.secondLabel.heightAnchor constant:8.0f],
    
    heightConstraint
]];
```

Here is what it looks like when run on the device. The labels are all short, except the first one, which is supposed to span several lines. But for some reason, it is being truncated even though I have the number of lines set to 0 and I think the content hugging and content compression resistance priorities set to what I think should be correct.

[image]

Here are how my labels are defined:

```
- (UILabel *)firstLabel {
    if (!self->_firstLabel) {
        self->_firstLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self->_firstLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self->_firstLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        self->_firstLabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self->_firstLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        [self->_firstLabel setContentHuggingPriority:251 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
        [self->_firstLabel setContentHuggingPriority:251 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
        [self->_firstLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
        [self->_firstLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
        self->_firstLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentNatural;
        self->_firstLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
        self->_firstLabel.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines;
        self->_firstLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
        
        //TODO: remove this
        self->_firstLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    }
    return self->_firstLabel;
}

- (UILabel *)secondLabel {
    if (!self->_secondLabel) {
        self->_secondLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self->_secondLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self->_secondLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        self->_secondLabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self->_secondLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        [self->_secondLabel setContentHuggingPriority:251 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
        [self->_secondLabel setContentHuggingPriority:251 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
        [self->_secondLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
        [self->_secondLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
        self->_secondLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentNatural;
        self->_secondLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
        self->_secondLabel.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines;
        self->_secondLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
        
        //TODO: remove this
        self->_secondLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }
    return self->_secondLabel;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's pretty straightforward when you understand about constraint inequalities and priorities. Here, the label on the left is longer:

[image]

Here, the label on the right is longer:

[image]

The yellow view, which stands in for a table view cell here, is sized to the larger of the labels.

How is that done? In addition to the labels being pinned top, left, and right in the normal way, the superview (yellow view) bottom has two greater-than-or-equal constraints, one to the bottom of each label; and it is itself given a very small height at a very low priority (as a way of telling the layout engine to make the height as small as possible while still obeying the inequalities, which would otherwise be ambiguous).

---

**EDIT** There appears to be some doubt that this would work for an actual table view, so here's proof that it does.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I have added the constraints like you mentioned, but I am still unable to get the table view cell to autosize based on the maximum label height. I have added a screenshot of my constraints and what it looks like in Interface Builder. Do you know what I am doing wrong? I am just trying to get the table view cell to sized based on the larger of the two, but even if I have just one label and I put a constraint from the bottom of the label to the bottom of the content view, the table view cell still does not autosize. Do you know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry for the additional comment, but I also just added another update that adds the constraints that I am using in code. I was just using Interface Builder to sort of prototype the design, and then implement it in code. I also included a screenshot of what it looks like on the device. The first item should be taking up multiple lines, but it is getting truncated instead. Do you see what I am doing wrong? Sorry for so many questions. Oh, and great book by the way. I have your "Programming iOS 12" book and I have just started reading through it. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Okay so, looking at your code, you are not doing any of what I said to do. So naturally you don’t get the same result I do. My answer was all about bottom constraints, but your code has no bottom constraints at all; the word “bottom” never even appears.

Comment: I updated it so the height constraints were replaced with bottom constraints and I think that fixed the issue, though I cannot tell for sure since the table view cells never grow. I think it is a separate issue, so I opened a new question for this. Do you notice anything at all wrong I am doing in there that would prevent the table view cell from growing and that would cause the labels to be compressed? Thank you again for your help and your time. I appreciate it very much. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67337925/uitableviewcell-not-autosizing

Comment: I've added a screen shot to prove that what I've said here works for a table view. I don't understand why you keep asking the question over and over when I've given you the info you need, if only you would actually do the thing I'm saying and not some other thing.

Comment: thank you for your help and I did what you said and it worked. I asked the other question because I still could not get the cell to change sizes, but that was because I was incorrectly adding the labels directly to the cell and not the contentView. I am new to iOS development and I am trying to learn, but there is a lot to learn to even get seemingly simple things to work. I am sorry for all the questions, I am just not sure how to debug these layout issues myself. I have tried to use the Xcode view debugger, but I apparently do not know how to use that either. Either way, thank you.