# UILabel not showing all text

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint

I have two labels in a UITableViewCell subclass. I want both labels to be multiline labels, so I have set the number of lines to zero for both of the labels. But the problem is that the labels keep getting truncated. For example, I have made the text size of the right label much larger so that it is taller but then I have added a lot of text to the first label on the left. But, rather than keep wrapping and adding more lines, it just truncates when it is the same size as the label on the right.

[image]

But the label on the left should have had a lot more text displayed and it should have taken several more lines, but instead it is truncated when it gets to the height of the other label. It is almost like I have a height constraint between the two labels, but I do not.

Here is the code I am using for this. The first part is the table view cell subclass that has the two labels - firstLabel (the one on the left) and secondLabel (the one on the right). Next, I have the code for the view that has the table view and shows how the table view is configured. Finally, there is a UITableView subclass that sets the intrinsicContentSize of the table to be the content size of the table. I added this because without this the table frame always stayed at zero and so the table view data source methods were not getting called. If anyone knows a better way to do this too, that would be much appreciated.

#### UITableViewCell subclass

This is the implementation for my UITableViewCell. I have vertical content hugging and content compression priorities for both labels, but I have tried this with and without these priorities and the result is the same.

```
@interface MyTableViewCell ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *firstLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *secondLabel;

@end

@implementation MyTableViewCell

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initialize {
    [self.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor systemTealColor]];
    [self.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor systemGrayColor]];
    
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.firstLabel];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.secondLabel];
    
    NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [self.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:1.0f];
    [heightConstraint setPriority:50];
    
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        [self.firstLabel.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor],
        [self.firstLabel.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor],
        [self.firstLabel.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.centerXAnchor constant:-4.0f],
        
        [self.secondLabel.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.centerXAnchor constant:4.0f],
        [self.secondLabel.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor],
        [self.secondLabel.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor],
        
        [self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor constraintGreaterThanOrEqualToAnchor:self.firstLabel.bottomAnchor constant:20.0f],
        [self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor constraintGreaterThanOrEqualToAnchor:self.secondLabel.bottomAnchor constant:20.0f],
        
        heightConstraint
    ]];
}

- (UILabel *)firstLabel {
    if (!self->_firstLabel) {
        self->_firstLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self->_firstLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self->_firstLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        self->_firstLabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self->_firstLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        [self->_firstLabel setContentHuggingPriority:251 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
        [self->_firstLabel setContentHuggingPriority:251 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
        [self->_firstLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
        [self->_firstLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
        self->_firstLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentNatural;
        self->_firstLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
        self->_firstLabel.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines;
        self->_firstLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
        self->_firstLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    }
    return self->_firstLabel;
}

- (UILabel *)secondLabel {
    if (!self->_secondLabel) {
        self->_secondLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self->_secondLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self->_secondLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        self->_secondLabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self->_secondLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        [self->_secondLabel setContentHuggingPriority:251 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
        [self->_secondLabel setContentHuggingPriority:251 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
        [self->_secondLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
        [self->_secondLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
        self->_secondLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentNatural;
        self->_secondLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
        self->_secondLabel.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines;
        self->_secondLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
        self->_secondLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }
    return self->_secondLabel;
}

- (void)setData:(MyModel *)data {
    self.firstLabel.text = data.first;
    self.secondLabel.text = data.second;
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}

@end
```

#### Primary View - has a table view as a child view

This is the actual view that is displayed. As part of the larger application, this view is then displayed in a vertical UIStackView.

This view has a table view as the only subview and the table view is pinned to the edges of this view with AutoLayout. The UITableView is actually an instance of another class called "AutosizingTableView" to get the table view to autosize (without this, the frame of the table stays at zero and the table view data source method, `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, was never being called since the table height was zero. The code for this table view is included after this section.

```
@interface MyView ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) AutosizingTableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation MyView

- (instancetype)init {
    return [self initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:coder]) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initialize {
    [self addSubview:self.tableView];
    
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        [self.tableView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.leadingAnchor],
        [self.tableView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topAnchor],
        [self.tableView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.trailingAnchor],
        [self.tableView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bottomAnchor],
        [self.tableView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.widthAnchor]
    ]];
}

- (UITableView *)tableView {
    if (!self->_tableView) {
        self->_tableView = [[AutosizingTableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        self->_tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self->_tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
        self->_tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
        self->_tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
        self->_tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
        self->_tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        self->_tableView.delegate = self;
        self->_tableView.dataSource = self;
        [self->_tableView registerClass:[MyTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myTableViewCell"];
    }
    return self->_tableView;
}

- (void)setdata:(NSArray<MyData *> *)data {
    self->_data = data;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.data.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    MyData *data = self.data[indexPath.row];
    cell.detail = detail;
    return cell;
}

@end
```

#### AutosizingTableView

As was mentioned in the previous section, this is just to make it so the table view autosizes. Without this, the table view height was zero and stayed at zero since the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method was never getting called because of the table view height.

```
@implementation AutosizingTableView

- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    return self.contentSize;
}

- (void)setContentSize:(CGSize)contentSize {
    [super setContentSize:contentSize];
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}

@end
```

Comment: So here we are _again_ even though the question has been answered twice already. I suggest you throw away all the extra stuff and just make yourself a simple table view app with none of the stack view self-sizing business, and persuade yourself that this works correctly there. Then you can investigate the added complexity of the stack view.

Comment: (Also I have a feeling you don't actually need `heightConstraint`. Plus your code has a _lot_ of unnecessary stuff; you should just prune it way down to get the minimal working example, as in my answer earlier.)

Comment: @matt this is yet another issue. I have had several issues with this table so far, but they are all different issues. The first was to size the cell based on the height of the taller label. Your suggestion to add the inequality was correct and I thank you for that. The next issue I had was that I was adding the labels to the cell directly, instead of to the contentView. This issue is different still. Here, for some reason the taller label is being truncated based on the height of the shorter label (or that is what it seems to be doing). I am not sure how to troubleshoot or fix that.

Comment: @matt I added the heightConstraint because I thought you said to do that. I may have misinterpreted what you suggested on your first response and I am sorry if I did. But what I interpreted your suggestion saying was to add the inequality constraint between the bottom of each label to the bottom of the cell. Then, I thought there was the suggestion to make one more constraint, that was low priority, that set the height to a short height and this would remove ambiguity, and then it would be overridden by the other constraints. I am sorry if I misunderstood. I am still new to AutoLayout.

Comment: @ashipma - I agree with matt... you are doing some very odd things here, most of which should not be needed. Start simple... plain table view, cell class with the two labels... get that working. ***Then*** - assuming you have a reason for embedding the table view in another view and wanting it to auto-size it's height - work on *that* part.

Comment: @DonMag Welcome aboard, you might want to start tracking this from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67326104/autosize-uitableviewcell-with-two-columns/67328317

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit difficult to know for certain, because you didn't provide a complete working example, but this *may* fix your issue.

See the comments for changes:

```
@interface MyTableViewCell ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *firstLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *secondLabel;

@end

@implementation MyTableViewCell

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initialize {
    [self.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor systemTealColor]];
    [self.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor systemGrayColor]];
    
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.firstLabel];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.secondLabel];
    
    // not needed
    //NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [self.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:1.0f];
    //[heightConstraint setPriority:50];
    
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        [self.firstLabel.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor],
        [self.firstLabel.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor],
        [self.firstLabel.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.centerXAnchor constant:-4.0f],
        
        [self.secondLabel.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.centerXAnchor constant:4.0f],
        [self.secondLabel.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor],
        [self.secondLabel.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor],
        
        [self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor constraintGreaterThanOrEqualToAnchor:self.firstLabel.bottomAnchor constant:20.0f],
        [self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor constraintGreaterThanOrEqualToAnchor:self.secondLabel.bottomAnchor constant:20.0f],
        
        // not needed
        //heightConstraint
    ]];
}

- (UILabel *)firstLabel {
    if (!self->_firstLabel) {
        self->_firstLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self->_firstLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self->_firstLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        self->_firstLabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        
        // not needed
        //self->_firstLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        //[self->_firstLabel setContentHuggingPriority:251 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
        //[self->_firstLabel setContentHuggingPriority:251 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
        //[self->_firstLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
        //[self->_firstLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
        
        self->_firstLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentNatural;
        
        // word-wrapping, not truncating
        //self->_firstLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
        self->_firstLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        
        self->_firstLabel.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines;
        self->_firstLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
        self->_firstLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    }
    return self->_firstLabel;
}

- (UILabel *)secondLabel {
    if (!self->_secondLabel) {
        self->_secondLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self->_secondLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self->_secondLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        self->_secondLabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        
        // not needed
        //self->_secondLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        //[self->_secondLabel setContentHuggingPriority:251 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
        //[self->_secondLabel setContentHuggingPriority:251 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
        //[self->_secondLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
        //[self->_secondLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];

        self->_secondLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentNatural;
        
        // word-wrapping, not truncating
        //self->_secondLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
        self->_secondLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        
        self->_secondLabel.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines;
        self->_secondLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
        self->_secondLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }
    return self->_secondLabel;
}

- (void)setData:(MyData *)data {
    self.firstLabel.text = data.first;
    self.secondLabel.text = data.second;
    
    // this is needed
    [self.firstLabel layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.secondLabel layoutIfNeeded];
    
    // not needed
    //[self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response. I will try this out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly the sort of thing I was referring to in my comment when I said to eliminate unnecessary stuff.

Comment: Thank you so much. That fixed the issue. I am not sure exactly which change fixed it though. Maybe it was changing the line break mode from truncate to word wrap, but I was thinking that the label would only truncate the text if it could not increase its size anymore, which since it was in a table view cell that was supposed to grow, it should always be able to increase the size. Anyway, thank you again for your help.

Comment: @matt and DonMag - thank you to both of you for your help with these issues. I really appreciate it and I am sorry for all the questions, I just wasn't sure if I should be putting all this in one giant question or several smaller ones. Anyway, I did add an update to this question titled "Update - a high level overview of what I am trying to do" in which I explain roughly what I am working on and how it is structured to see if either of you have suggestions or comments on how to layout a UI that has different dynamically sized sections. I go into more detail in the edit. Thank you again.